# Is the negation of „net“ present in all of Germany?

Tags: negation, comparison

I just wondered after a talk with a someone from Austria from the usage of „net“ (he didn’t know this) like here:

> Ich kenne das nicht.

> Ich kenne das net.

Is this a phenomenon of whole Germany?

Comment: This is a regional thing. I personaly know it primarily in the Hessian dialect, but can‘t say if this is common for other dialects as well. It always sounds „southern“ to me, I never heard it in northern Germany.

Comment: In the eastern reagions they say _Ich kenn das ni._

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: there is no such thing as "the eastern regions". Not if you claim *they* say "ni". Because this is primarily part of saxon dialects and neither north nor south of it (Passau is almost as east as Dresden)

Comment: @Shegit Yes, saxon specifically.

Comment: [This](https://www.atlas-alltagssprache.de/runde-2/f25e/) map (Atlas  zur  deutschen  Alltagssprache) should be  useful.

Comment: In case I use "net", I would say "Ich kenn das net" - thus omit the second e on kenne.

Comment: Hoffmansthal famously employed _nit_ in a rather weird attempt to create an artsy language: _Fürwahr mag länger das nit ertragen, Daß alle Kreatur gegen mich Ihr Herz verhärtet böslich_ (and so on through _Jedermann_).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The wonderful resource *Atlas der deutschen Alltagssprache* [asked about how an unemphasised *nicht* is pronounced in everyday speech](https://www.atlas-alltagssprache.de/runde-2/f25e/) and aggregated the result to give the following map:

[image: Map showing the distribution of different forms of colloquial nicht across the German-speaking area.]

As you can see, Germany is essentially North/South split on this pronunciation (like many others). *Net* and its cousins *nit, ned, niad, nidda, nöd* and *it* can be heard all across the South and southern centre with the northern boundary being approximately from the Hunsrück to the Saxony/Czechia border. North of this line, the predominant form is *nich*, sometimes *nisch* or *nech* (the latter is not separately distinguished in the map). Saxony itself presents somewhat of a special case as the dominant form is *ni* which lacks both the /ç/ sound and the /t/ sound.

The stray *ni* dots in the far North are slightly confusing to me and the accompanying text does not go into detail. This could be residual influence of the northern *Platt* dialects or somehow related to the proximity to Denmark (although in that case I would expect them to be even further north).

Answer (score 0):

The shift from *nicht* to *ned*, *net*, *nöd* and *nüt* is a phenomenon that occurs in many  mittel- and oberdeutsch dialects (so, roughly, in all regions south of the Main river), that includes Austria and Switzerland. See [Grimm's Wörterbuch](http://woerterbuchnetz.de/cgi-bin/WBNetz/wbgui_py?sigle=DWB&mode=Vernetzung&lemid=GN04912#XGN04912)

Obviously, dialects tend to sneak into spoken Hochdeutsch every now and then, so you might hear "net" everywhere there.

Comment: @Jan "everywhere there" is something different than "everywhere". Please read again. There's even a hint in the answer on where exactly "everywhere there" might be. Braunschweig is definitely north of "south of the Main river".

Comment: You are correct, I completely missed the there there! I apologise.